Severe memory leak with Hotwire Turbo and Shopify
I'm encountering a significant memory leak when integrating Turbo with my Shopify store. After each Turbo-driven navigation, the heap size increases due to detached DOM nodes being retained, leading to eventual browser crashes.
Problem Description:
Setup: Basic Turbo setup with <turbo-frame id="main" data-turbo-action="advance"> wrapping the primary content area.
The memory leak persists even after removing all custom JavaScript. Both paid and free themes exhibit the issue.
Observation:
Heap snapshots indicate entire DOM trees from previous pages are being retained. Switching to PJAX resolves the issue, suggesting that Turbo's handling of Shopify’s dynamic updates is causing the problem.
Reproduction Steps:
Create a basic Shopify theme or use an existing one with the following Turbo setup:
Add Turbo via CDN in the theme.liquid file:
<script src="https://cdn.skypack.dev/@hotwired/turbo"></script>

Wrap the primary content area with a Turbo frame:
<turbo-frame id="main" data-turbo-action="advance"\>

{{ content_for_layout }}

</turbo-frame\>

Navigate through different pages in the store using Turbo navigation.
Use Chrome DevTools to monitor memory usage (Heap snapshots).
Observe exponential heap growth after multiple navigations, with thousands of detached DOM nodes being retained.
Question:
Is there a known conflict between Turbo’s DOM caching and Shopify’s dynamic section rendering? Are there any strategies or known solutions to resolve this memory leak?
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!
My preview store-front: https://3u1zu7mqw4qn0hsi-66860908835.shopifypreview.com
What I've Tried:
Disabling Turbo Frames: Removed all <turbo-frame> elements to test if the problem is isolated to frame management. Memory leak persisted, indicating the issue is likely related to Turbo Drive’s page management or element caching.

Manual Node Replacement: Tried replacing document.body using cloneNode(true) after each navigation to reset event listeners and fully clear retained elements. This worked briefly but introduced new issues with duplicated state and broken references in certain Shopify components.

Using Turbo’s data-turbo-permanent Attributes: Wrapped key elements like the header and footer with data-turbo-permanent to preserve them between navigations. The issue persisted, with even these "permanent" elements being held in memory, causing a buildup of nodes.

Dynamic Script Loading Strategies: Tested various script loading strategies (defer, async, dynamic imports) for Shopify-specific scripts that were interfering with Turbo’s caching. No improvement—memory still ballooned after multiple page changes.

Complete Removal of theme.js: Removed the entire theme.js file and related scripts to isolate the issue. Surprisingly, the memory leak still occurred, indicating the root cause is not in the custom JavaScript but likely in Turbo’s own handling of Shopify’s dynamic architecture.

Unregistering and Reinitializing Sections Manually: Attempted to manually flush and reinitialize Shopify sections using Shopify.designMode hooks and Turbo’s lifecycle events (turbo:before-fetch-request, turbo:frame-render). This worked on the first navigation but broke after repeated renders, showing that Turbo is not fully cleaning up DOM structures after navigation.

Switching to PJAX for Comparison: Implemented PJAX for navigation instead of Turbo. PJAX worked without any memory leaks, confirming that the issue is specific to Turbo’s handling of elements and DOM caching.



don't inline document.addEventListener("turbo:load"... every time you navigate a page you add another event listener on top. this should only be done once on initial page load.

Thank you for your suggestion! Unfortunately, the issue persists even when no ("turbo:load"... code is present. The memory leak occurs even when the only thing loaded on the site is the Turbo CDN in the .
I’ve gone as far as completely removing all JavaScript from the site, and the memory leak still happens after each navigation. I guess this indicates that the issue is not related to event listener duplication but rather something deeper in how Turbo Drive is handling Shopify’s DOM updates?
Any further insights or suggestions would be much appreciated!

some memory increase would be expected, turbo takes snapshots of every page for caching https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/building#opting-out-of-caching

I believe the issue comes from loading the package from a CDN. I accidentally left a  package that I was testing in from unpkg and I was having severe memory issues on page navigation. Once I (correctly) removed it from the  all memory issues went away for me.
